# Calculating multi-objective shortest path for a graph in Mathematica

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, algorithm

I would like to calculate multi-objective shortest path for a graph which edges have multiple weights (distance, delay, cost, for example) using e.g. Martins' algorithm. Is it possible doing that using built-in functions of Mathematica? If not, what could I do?

Comment: No, this algorithm is not built in.  You have to implement it from scratch.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Any advise how could I assign an array of weights like [3, 5, 7] to an edge?

Answer (score 3):

In this context "shortest" has meaning only for an effective scalar value at each weight.  So if you have several edge properties (distance, delay, cost, etc.), then you must first create a function that reduces the set of edge properties into a single scalar "weight" for each edge.  It could be, for instance, $w = dis + 2 delay + 5 cost$.  (Weights should be non-negative, in general.)

Once you have such a scalar for each weight, grouped into a list, use, for example:

```
mygraph = PetersenGraph[4, 1, 
    EdgeWeight -> {3,2,8,5,6,2,9,4,1,8,12,1}]
```

and then

```
FindShortestPath[mygraph, 1, All]
```

Comment: David, obviously, your proposal (using so-called _Composite Objective_) is not equal to multi-objective optimization in general. That is why, Martins has proposed his algorithm of multi-criteria shortest path, which finds an optimal path by processing multiple objectives simultaneously.